# IF rule for all stages in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

Is there a way to define a rule for all stages in jenkins.
I have a global env and want to convert it for all stages, not just stage by stage.
Is it possible and how?

Comment: It seems like you should just not trigger the pipeline in that case instead of skipping every stage.

Comment: It is not a rule about whether to start a stage or not. It is a rule once you get the parameter to "redefine it" before the stages start